# How can I resolve Grid layout problem in this case?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I've got some problems when I'am trying to make my section with Grid layout. Where exactly I make mistake? Can someone explaine me, please?

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="item1"><span>Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="item2"><span>Item 2</span></div>
        <div class="item3"><span>Item 3</span></div>
        <div class="item4"><span>Item 4</span></div>
        <div class="item5"><span>Item 5</span></div>
    </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #969d9f;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #969d9f;
}

.grid-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 1200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4, .item5 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #636564;
    height: 360px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.item1 { width: 750px; }

.item2 { width: 360px; }

.item3 { width: 555px; }

.item4 { width: 555px; }

.item5 { width: 1200px; }
```

So the main question is how can I correctly display my blocks and where is my main mistake that I make? 
 Here is some pics:
[image: This is how it looks right now]
[image: And that's how I need to display them]
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout isn't a "*normal*" grid (your rows 1 & 2 have cells with different widths from each other), so to resolve it, a solution could be to create more columns (3/4/5 columns: it depends by cells width and if the biggests [1&4] are equals or not) and play, for example, with `grid-template-areas` to create items that can... "fill more than 1 cell": in background there is a grid, but with this "trick" you can transform it as your layout.

This is a useful guide for more informations about CSS grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Another solution is to use flexbox also for those rows :-)

Try it:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #969d9f;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    /*height: 100vh;*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #969d9f;
}

.grid-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:1200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
    "item1 item1 item1 item2"
    "item3 item4 item4 item4"
    "item5 item5 item5 item5";
}



.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4, .item5 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #636564;
    height: 360px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

/*.item1 { width: 750px; }

.item2 { width: 360px; }

.item3 { width: 555px; }

.item4 { width: 555px; }

.item5 { width: 1200px; }*/

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: item4;
}

.item5 {
  grid-area: item5;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="item1"><span>Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="item2"><span>Item 2</span></div>
        <div class="item3"><span>Item 3</span></div>
        <div class="item4"><span>Item 4</span></div>
        <div class="item5"><span>Item 5</span></div>
    </div>
 </header>
```

P.S. Maybe it is better don't use a fixed widths in a world of mobile device, so I changed your `witdh:1200px` with a `max-width:1200px`, but well you can change it 
if you do not care about it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for advice! I’m gonna try out your solution! Hope it’ll work correctly for me :)

Answer (score 1):

its my opinion

HTML

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="item1"><span>Item 1</span></div>
        <div class="item2"><span>Item 2</span></div> 
        <div class="item3"><span>Item 3</span></div>
        <div class="item4"><span>Item 4</span></div>
        <div class="item5"><span>Item 5</span></div>
    </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #969d9f;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #969d9f;
}

.grid-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 1200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: "item1 item1 item2"           /* make grid area */
                         "item3 item4 item4"
                         "item5 item5 item5";

    grid-template-columns:(1fr, 1fr, 1fr);             /* set width of colums */
}



.item1, .item2, .item3, .item4, .item5 {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #636564;
    height: 360px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.item1 {grid-area: item1}            /* connect items with grid area */

.item2 {grid-area: item2}

.item3 {grid-area: item3}

.item4 {grid-area: item4}

.item5 {grid-area: item5}
```

Comment: Sorry, make a mistake with grid item widhts!!!
See ReSedano comment above!